# works perfectly when running in debug, but not on server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

for some reason this works perfectly, when i do it in debug mode it adds the tasks to stagingtable, and then transfers none duplicates to the regular table. However, when i upload it to the server it does not work.

any ideas

```
Using bcp As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(connstring)

bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 1)
bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 2)
bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 3)
bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 4)
bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 7)
bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(5, 5)
bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(6, 10)
bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(7, 13)
bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(8, 6)
bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.stagingtasks"


bcp.WriteToServer(table)

If conn.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
    conn.Close()
End If

If conn1.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
    conn1.Close()
End If

End Using


cmd1.CommandText = "dbo.taskadding"
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd1.Connection = conn

conn.Open()
cmd1.BeginExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()


atasks.Visible = False
UpdatePanel2.Update()
Label2.Visible = False


Catch ex As Exception
    Label2.Text = ex.ToString
    'Label2.Visible = True
    UpdatePanel2.Update()
End Try
```

Comment: What exatly isnt working? Is there an error? We have no way of telling whats wrong here.

Comment: Is the `connectionstring` correct on the server?

Comment: sorry, if i wasnt clear. what i was trying to say was that it only updates one table, which is beingupdated by the bulk copy, however, it does not run the stored procedure. even though it does run and work fine in debug mode

Comment: so the coding works it just doesnt work on the server i guess

Answer (score 0):

Does the process that runs this have EXEC rights to the proc?

Comment: im pretty sure it does as, it works after i reupload the file to the server. but ill come to work the next day and it will stop working again